# Test if a iterator is last in list

Tags: c++, c++17

I created this iterator to go through a list of ports.  I want to add commas to each port, except for the last port.   To do this, I thought I could test `it == ( verilogPorts.end() - 1)` which seems to work.....

Should I be using a VerilogPort.size() or something other than verilogPorts.end() - 1?
Seems like -1 is potentially a problem.

```
 for (std::list<VerilogPort>::iterator it = verilogPorts.begin(); it != verilogPorts.end(); ++it) {
        add_comma = (it == (verilogPorts.end() - 1));
        if (port_section != "") {
            port_section = port_section + "/n";
        }
        port_section = port_section  + it->get_port_string_and_comment(add_comma);
    }
```

Comment: Define "seems to work". It definitely shouldn't compile.

Comment: Yeah.  I think I have a bigger problem here.  The types don't even match.   But it did compile.  Maybe I have a Makefile problem too.  Let me poke at it a bit more...

Comment: Instead of adding the comma last, you can also add it first, if you are not at the start. That's much easier: `if (it != verilogPort.begin()) port_section += ","; port_section += it->get_port_string_and_comment();`

Comment: I tried that first, which was how I got the successful compile, but the format of the output is like this 
input Some_Port_Name, // Some comment.   So the comma goes before a comment.  When I implemented it as you suggested, the comma was coming after the comment which was bad, and caused the Verilog compiler to throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so solved like this using the distance function.  Relative to the comment above about not compiling.  I validated that the Makefile had an issue, and a stale executable was being left after the error.  I don't really know if this is a "good" solution to not.

```
for (std::list<VerilogPort>::iterator it = verilogPorts.begin(); it != verilogPorts.end(); ++it) {
            add_comma = (std::distance(it, verilogPorts.end()) != 1);
            if (port_section != "") {
                port_section = port_section + "\n";
            }
            port_section = port_section  + it->get_port_string_and_comment(add_comma);
        }
```